# Writing to Buffered Writer UTF-8 Characters With Accents Are Coming Out Garbled

Tags: java, utf-8, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I am reading from a UTF-8 input file with accented characters, reading the lines and writing them back to a different file (also UTF-8) but the accented characters are coming out garbled in the output. For instance the following words:

León

Mānoa

are output as:

Leï¿½n

Manoa

I've looked at about 100 answers to this question which all suggest reading and writing the files as the code indicates below, but I keep having the same result.

I've broken down the code to the elemental features below:

```
public class UTF8EncoderTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader inputFileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("utf8TestInput.txt"), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedWriter outputFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("utf8TestOutput.txt"), "UTF-8"));

            String line = inputFileReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) 
            {
                outputFileWriter.write(line + "\r\n");          
                line = inputFileReader.readLine();
            }
            inputFileReader.close();
            outputFileWriter.close();

            System.out.println("Finished!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

But this still results in garbled characters in the output file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [search Stackoverflow for this](/help/how-to-ask): I can guarantee you the answer is already here.

Comment: As stated in the question, I've scoured StackOverflow for the answer to this, they've all given the same answer which is what is coded up above.

BufferedReader inputFileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("utf8TestInput.txt"), "UTF-8"));

and

BufferedWriter outputFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("utf8TestOutput.txt"), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Can you provide a raw hex dump of the input and output files you're testing with?

Comment: Then it's a reasonable assumption that what you're reading in isn't actually UTF-8 at all. What are the first few bytes in your input file?

Comment: `León` in UTF-8 is bytes `4C 65 C3 B3 6E`. `Leï¿½n` in UTF-8 is bytes `4C 65 EF BF BD 6E`. `EF BF BD` is the UTF-8 encoded form of Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`. Whatever bytes the input string `León` was encoded in, it WAS NOT UTF-8, causing your `InputStreamReader` to misinterpret the `ó` (codepoint U+00F3) and replace it with codepoint U+FFFD in your `line` variable, which your `OutputStreamWriter` then (correctly) wrote out in UTF-8 as bytes `EF BF BD`. So double check the encoding of the input file, it is NOT what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String sText = "This león and this is Mānoa";
    File oFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir("YourFolder"), "YourFile.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream oFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(oFile, true); //append
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(oFileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        writer.append(sText);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {            
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code with your examples and it works without problems (characters are not changed or lost).

Few tips when you deal with charsets in Java:

1. Default character encoding in Java is the character encoding used by JVM.
2. By default, JVM uses platform encoding i.e. character encoding of your server (OS).
3. Java gets character encoding by calling `System.getProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8")` at the time of JVM start-up. So if Java doesn't get any `file.encoding` attribute it uses `UTF-8` character encoding. Most **important point** to remember is that Java caches character encoding or value of system property `file.encoding` in most of its core classes like `InputStreamReader`, which needs character encoding after JVM started. So if you change system property `file.encoding` programmatically when application is running you will not see desired effect (change) in your application and that's why you should always work with your own character encoding provided to your application and if its need to be set than set character encoding or charset while you start JVM.

How to get default character encoding?

1. The easiest way to get default character encoding is to call `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`, which will return default character encoding if JVM started with `-Dfile.encoding` property or program has not called `System.setProperty("file.encoding", someEncoding)`.
2. `java.nio.Charset` provides a convenient static method `Charset.defaultCharset()` which returns default character encoding.
3. By using `InputStreamReader#getEncoding()`.

How to set default character encoding?

1. By providing the `file.encoding` system property when JVM starts e.g.:
   `java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" HelloWorld`
2. If you don't have control how JVM starts up, you can set environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-16"` or any other character encoding, and it will be picked up when JVM starts in your windows machine. JVM will also print `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF16` on console to indicate that it has picked `JAVA_TOOS_OPTIONS`.

Alternatively, you can try:

```
Path inputFilePath = Paths.get("utf8TestInput.txt");
BufferedReader inputFileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Path outputFilePath = Paths.get("utf8TestOutput");
BufferedWriter outputFileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```